# Issue with an developed ionic app for android

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, cordova, ionic-framework

Currently i am working with ionic app development i can developed an app using ionic framework but if i would install an application in my phone or any other android device that phone get stuck and restarts automatically.following is the plugin list used in my app

"Google Play Services for Android"
"Keyboard"
 "PushPlugin"
"Console"
"Device"
"Notification"
"Splashscreen"
"Whitelist"
"Toast"
"Diagnostic"
"Camera"
 "File"
"File Transfer"
"InAppBrowser"
Is it possible to remove this issue from my app please suggest me some solution 
Thanks in adv...

Comment: You need to supply way more information for anyone to be of help. If your app causes a platform crash it's a serious issue, you need to get a hold of logs, model and version numbers and any error message you can find.

Comment: sir there is no error message and no warning or anything in console.Main thing is app behaves normal in some phone and in some phone like moto e,asus zenphone 5,sony experia it will behaves as explained

Comment: #1 Remove all the plugins #2 Add only one #3 Install your application on a device which restarted in the past. If the device does not restart, add another plugin. Keep doing this until you find the plugin that is causing crash. Get information about the plugin to diagnose the root cause